# Cosa significa "scozzonare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> 1943. Lo stato di guerra cominciò a **scozzonare** il nostro gruppo. Primo a partire fu uno degli amici non attori, Umberto, fiera natura di giramondo, striata di profumi rimbaldini. Partì infatti quasi contento, per il fronte africano, dove fu subito fatto prigioniero dagli inglesi e trascorse un paio d'anni dietro il filo spinato.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire "scozzonare" in questo brano. Ho letto le due [accezioni che appaiono nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scozzonare/), ma non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di questo verbo nel testo sopra citato?

Comment: La mia impressione, polarizzata dalla mia origine, è che derivi dal meridionalismo cozzo: il cozzo di pane è la parte estremamente di una pagnotta oblunga (ad esempio il filone) tagliata ed opportunamente svuotata della mollica per accogliere il companatico, che può consistere in minestre e zuppe oppure preparazioni più complesse (tra cui sottolineerei la parmigiana di melanzane). Nel caso specifico il gruppo di amici veniva ad essere continuamente privato delle *estremità* ovvero dei giovani chiamati alle armi.

Answer (score 2):

Penso si riferisca al senso figurato di ***scozzonare***. Il significato della frase è che lo stato di guerra cominciò insegnare  , far apprendere al gruppo di amici sia come  combattere ma anche come   crescere per affrontare l'aspetto più duro della vita:

> - 2. In senso fig., ***far apprendere i primi elementi di una disciplina, di un’arte, di un mestiere; rendere più esperto e capace; far diventare meno rozzo e impacciato:*** ho mandato mio figlio da un mio amico pittore perché lo scozzoni nella tecnica dei colori; gli apprendisti, prima di lasciarli lavorare da soli, vanno un po’ scozzonati; volgarizzamenti, che tanto conferirono a s. la favella e scaltrirla (Carducci).

Btw (Il termine è molto raro)

Answer (score 1):

Dal contesto mi sembra plausibile che Gassman si sia confuso fra due verbi simili, "scozzare" e "scozzonare".

"[Scozzare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scozzare/)" (un mazzo di carte) vale *rimescolare*, generalmente prelevandone le estremità (i *cozzi*) e reinserendole nel mezzo, o [prelevandone i singoli semi](http://www.etimo.it/?term=scozzare).

La guerra dunque non scozzona, ma *scozza* il gruppo togliendone alcuni elementi e forse rimescolando gli altri.